# How can I pass gui batch arguments in Windows XP/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, batch-file

Is there any straightforward way to call a .bat file and have it prompt me for each of the arguments that will replace the %1 %2 and so forth fields?  I can memorize their order just fine and run it from the command line, but it would be preferable for friends & family if there was an icon they could just click and get the appropriate prompts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo "Parameter 1" 
set /p p1=
echo "Parameter 2"
set /p p2=
[...]
yourcommand.exe %p1% %p2% [...]
```

`@echo off` stops commands being printed. We will ask for a parameter each using `echo`, `set /p p1=` asks the user for some input (use "return" or "enter" to confirm) and stores it into variable `%p1%`. In the last line you can call your program with the parameters entered.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does? Especially the `set` statements.

Comment: `set` just asks for some input and stores it into a variable.

Comment: As a note, at least for some versions of windows (I haven't tested) the set commands can be simplified to set /p pn="Parameter n: "

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the user for parameters with `set /p`.

Optionally, you can check if `%1` exists first. e.g. with `if "%1"==""` or something similar.