# How to make a batch file that takes in arguments and executes findstr using user input and shows results

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

This is intended to make a search easier on an individual, and the command line makes people give up. How could I go about having user input be passed through findstr by just using batch files?

Comment: [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am not asking for any code. I just don't know where to begin when it comes to implementing a gui solution.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I found this post in the related posts sidebar, and it solves my problem to a good extent: [How can I pass gui batch arguments in Windows XP/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/352179/how-can-i-pass-gui-batch-arguments-in-windows-xp-7?rq=1)